# Receiving 'Project not found' errors when using `gcloud deploy app`

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Running the command `gcloud app deploy --project=my-project-name` gives me the following output:

```
$ gcloud app deploy --project=my-project-name
You are about to deploy the following services:
 - my-project-name/my-service-name/20160922t110054 (from [/usr/local/projects/my-project/app.yaml])
     Deployed URL: [https://my-service-name-dot-my-project-name.appspot.com]

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  Y

WARNING: We couldn't validate that your project is ready to deploy to App Engine Flexible Environment. If deployment fails, please try again.
Beginning deployment of service [my-service-name]...
WARNING: Deployment of App Engine Flexible Environment apps is currently in Beta
Building and pushing image for service [my-service-name]
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Project [my-project-name] not found.
```

As you can see, it's claiming the project isn't found. What's confusing me is that the project clearly appears under here:

```
$ gcloud projects list
PROJECT_ID       NAME               PROJECT_NUMBER
my-project-name  MyProject          980737858333
```

I can't find any other instance of this issue, and I've run out of ideas to troubleshoot. So what's the problem with the command I'm running? Or how else can I troubleshoot?

My `app.yaml` looks like this:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :8080 main.app
runtime: custom
vm: true

service: my-service-name
```

Comment: Are you using a service account? What role do you have on that project?

Comment: @ZacharyNewman I'm an editor on the project

Comment: What's really strange is that if I purposefully use a non-existent project name I get an error telling me I don't have the required permissions. Which  means in my original case it's successfully determined that I have permissions for the project before alerting me that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Very strange. I'll try to route this to the correct folks inside Google.

Comment: @ZacharyNewman Thanks, I really appreciate your help. I've just tried deploying to a separate random project of which I am the owner, and didn't hit the same roadblock. Does that signify it might be a permissions issue?

Comment: @ZacharyNewman I figured it out (answer posted below). Thanks again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out this is what happens if you don't have the "Google Cloud Container Builder API" enabled. I found this out by trying `--verbosity debug`, which displayed the link I had to follow to enable it for my project.

When deploying, the call to `https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project-name/builds?alt=json` returns a nice error message:

```
"The cloudbuild API is not enabled for project ID \"my-project-name\": to enable it, visit https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/cloudbuild.googleapis.com/overview?project=my-project-name"
```

It would be cool if that was displayed to the user in place of the "app not found" error

Comment: also use --log-http : which i've found is very helpful

Comment: I was following the go examples, but started again with a new project, this step seemed automated on the first run.... but had me scratching my head,
Your insight and link got me up and runnning again, much thanks.

Comment: You could have explained how to enable it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126481/gcloud-error-gcloud-app-deploy-permissions-error-fetching-application/56136326

Comment: At the time of writing, the link in the logs (like I mentioned above) took you straight to the page where you enable it. Does it no longer do that?