# gcloud - ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Permissions error fetching application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to deploy node js app on google cloud but getting following error -

```
Step #1: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Permissions error fetching application [apps
/mytest-240512]. Please make sure you are using the correct project ID and that
you have permission to view applications on the project.
```

I am running following command -

```
gcloud builds submit . --config cloudbuild.yaml
```

My cloudbuild.yaml file looks like -

```
steps:
  #install
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['install']

   #deploy
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['app', 'deploy']
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The default Cloud Build service account does not allow access to deploy App Engine. You need to enable the Cloud Build service account to perform actions such as deploy.

The Cloud Build service account is formatted like this:

```
[PROJECT_NUMBER]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
```

- Go to the Google Cloud Console -> IAM & admin -> IAM.
- Locate the service account and click the pencil icon.
- Add the role "App Engine Deployer" to the service account.

Wait a couple of minutes for the service account to update globally and then try again.

Comment: Thank you for your response John, I have to also enable - App engine API 
but now getting following message - 
Step #1: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Your deployment has succeeded, but promoting the new version to default failed. You may not have permissions to change traffic splits. Changing traffic splits requires the Owner, Editor, App Engine Admin, or App Engine Service Admin role. Please contact your project owner and use the `gcloud app services set-traffic --splits <version>=1` command to redirect traffic to your newly deployed version.

Comment: working now, after adding "App Engine Admin" role to [PROJECT_NUMBER]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com

Comment: I had assumed that you already had set up App Engine, which requires region selection, enabling services, etc. Now that you have an app deployed you should not need anything other than `gcloud app deploy` and `App Engine Deployer` permissions. It is OK to leave Cloud Build with App Engine Admin as that is a secure service controlled by Google.

Comment: is there any option in package.json to run command after build like heroku-postbuild

Comment: I am not sure. What are you trying to do? Note: I would create a new question for this to get a better chance of a good answer.

Comment: @SachinVairagi I found that the "Project Editor" plus "App Engine Deployer" permissions were sufficient to use Cloud Builder to deploy to GAE Standard Environment.

Comment: @hamx0r - Thank you for sharing your solution, it might help others.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same error today and the way I resolve it was by running: `$ gcloud auth login` on the console.

This will open a new browser tab for you to login with the credentials that has access to the project you're trying to deploy.

I was able to deploy to gcloud after that.

ps.: I'm not sure this is the best approach, but I'm leaving this as a possible solution as this is how I usually go around this problem. Worst case, I'll stand corrected and learn something new.

Comment: Thanks! This resolved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

You can also get this error if you forgot to enable billing on the project.
I just had to go to the Google Cloud Console, search for App Engine and the billing setup popped up.

Comment: Same for me. Once I enabled billing the deploy worked inmediatelly.

Answer (score 2):

Two commands can handle the perms needed (run in your terminal if you have gcloud sdk installed and authenticated or run in cloud shell for your project):

````
export PROJECT_ID=[[put your project id here]]
export PROJECT_NUMBER=$(gcloud projects describe $PROJECT_ID --format="value(projectNumber)")

gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_ID}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com \
--member=serviceAccount:${PROJECT_NUMBER}@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/iam.serviceAccountUser \
--project=${PROJECT_ID}
```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_ID} \
--member=serviceAccount:${PROJECT_NUMBER}@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com \
--role=roles/appengine.appAdmin
````

Comment: Thanks - worked well - just needed to remove the ``` to allow the full command to execute!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the issue was that I have mistaken project ID for project NAME