# Google app engine deployment using wrong service account?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have this app that's been running on Google App Engine for a good couple of years. Today I needed to modify its app.yaml file, but when I ran "gcloud app deploy" I got this error:

```
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [7] Failed to create cloud build: service account "redacted@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com" has insufficient permission to execute the build on project "redacted"
```

It appears that the default service account no longer has the necessary permissions. In fact, it may have been deleted completely, because I don't see it listed under `gcloud projects get-iam-policy xxxx`. What I see instead is this:

```
serviceAccount:service-redacted@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

with a correct-looking role `cloudbuild.serviceAgent`.

I tried googling any changes related to GAE service accounts but didn't find any useful references. I followed the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64236468/cloud-build-fails-to-deploy-to-google-app-engine-you-do-not-have-permission-to), but it didn't help.

The question is, how do I change the permissions of the service account mentioned in the original error message, or, how do I tell GAE to use another (correct) service account when deploying my app?

Comment: You can try to look for the service account in case it may have been deleted and then restore it. There's a guide in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#undeleting).

Answer (score 0):

1. According to [this][1] documentation
   ...*To deploy new versions, a member must have the Service Account User (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser) role on the App Engine default service account, and the Cloud Build Editor (roles/cloudbuild.builds.editor) and Cloud Storage Object Admin (roles/storage.objectAdmin) roles on the project*.....
2. Using the `IAM` page you can add the email address of the person deploying (the one you have authenticated via gcloud) and add the above roles to that email
   [1]: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles?hl=en#app-engine-roles

Comment: My account has the Owner role, which I believe is sufficient to deploy an app.

Comment: I tried adding these roles to my owner account, but as expected, it made no difference.